# Meaning of ですかね in a response

Tags: word-choice, nuances

I feel like this is a basic question, one whose meaning I don't think I fully understand. I'm watching a サンドウィッチマン コント on YouTube where 伊達さん is asked

"How many women have you been out with before?"

To which he pauses to think for a few seconds before replying with

> んー3人ぐらいですかね

My question is what is the nuance of ですかね over です here? Am I right to take it that by using ですかね, there is just a touch of uncertainty in his response? I.e he isn't 100% that it was just 3 people?

The original conversation:

> 富澤: 今まで何人ぐらいの女性とお付き合いされたことありますか。
>
> 伊達: 今までですか。
>
> 富澤: はい。
>
> 伊達: んー3人ぐらいですかね。

YouTube video for reference:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHh-_QmGESk&t=164s

Comment: And how does it compare to ～かな?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have pretty much answered your own question here.

「～～ですかね」 is a half-declarative and half-interrogative expression for making a statement that the speaker does not feel would need to be clear-cut.

It actually is used to mean what its components would literally suggest -- the interrogative 「か」 and the casual declarative 「ね」.

> "Uh.. About three, I guess?"

Comment: Mathiue Bouville's comment also makes a good point: What would the nuance be if it was かな over ですかね?

Comment: @Nubcake 「んー3人ぐらいかな。」←casual, 「んー3人ぐらいですかね。」←polite って感じですかね...

Comment: @Chocolate♦ -san, What would be the intonation be like with this use of かね? will it be a rising one or falling one?

Comment: @APK It has a falling tone at the end. It's like [ですかね]{HLLH}⤵.

Comment: ありがとう @chocolate san